# How to write Privacy Policy for iOS Application which uses the Health App

Tags: ios, privacy, policy, healthkit

Hi I'm making an iOS Application which uses the Health App and to submit this application in App Store I have to provide privacy policy, but I don't know what to write inside it because I'm not from USA and my English is not very well...

In [HealthKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014707) it's said:

You must also provide a privacy policy for any app that uses the HealthKit framework. You can find guidance on creating a privacy policy at the following sites:

Personal Health Record model (for non-HIPAA apps): http://www.healthit.gov/policy-researchers-implementers/personal-health-record-phr-model-privacy-notice
HIPAA model (for HIPAA covered apps): http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/modelnotices.html

My application only writes calories, proteins and sugars in the Health App, I don't know what is HIPPA and non-HIPAA what's the difference?
And Can someone give me an exaple privacy policy for this ?

Comment: I think you are asking this question the wrong place, SO is for coding and development of software. Not for Legal matters

Comment: This question shoukd be asked at StackExchange OR some of the other forums. It is not a 'programming specific question'

Comment: okay I'm sorry I'll ask it on StackExchange

Comment: I can't find where to ask can you tell me example website ?

Comment: This question requires legal advice to answer, not programming help. You should contact a lawyer for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HIPAA is a law in the United States which contains provisions to regulate personally identifiable health information. It was created to prevent entities that deal with medical records from being careless and letting patient records get stolen or misused.

[Here is a link that describes who is covered by HIPAA](http://www.hrsa.gov/healthit/toolbox/HIVAIDSCaretoolbox/SecurityAndPrivacyIssues/whoisreq2comply.html)

Assuming you are not covered by HIPAA, in the links you posted there is also a [generator](http://www.healthit.gov/policy-researchers-implementers/your-organizations-phr-data-practices) that looks like it will generate a sample privacy policy for you to use based on what kind of information you are processing and your entity details.